# Program Flow in C

Tags: c

I was just going through some questions and found this is one though the question asked about declaration and definition which know I understand thanks to stackoverflow.

```
int main()
{
extern int a;
printf("%d",a);
}
int a=20;
```

The flow of execution of C program is from top to bottom if it doesn't encounter any control statements, So in the above code **extern int a** declares a while **int a=20** defines a but this statement is even after main() terminated which results in the end of program, So why this code doesn't give any error Like Undefined symbol a ?

Comment: Short answer: C is a compiled language, not a scripting language.  To understand, you would need to look at the assembly code that the C compiler generates, and the object file format that allows the linker to tie everything together into an executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last `int a=20;` is not a statement but a *definition*. So the variable `a` is initialized before the start of the program.

<sup>(On Linux systems running an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable, the `a` is probably in some `data` segment, initialized at [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) time of your program)</sup>

The `extern int a;` *inside* `main` is a declaration of some global symbol (which in your case happens to be the variable `a` defined later).

You could have put the `int a=20;` in some other translation unit and build your program by linking both.

Read [Levine's book on *linkers and loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)

Comment: **The extern int a inside main is a declaration of some global symbol ** Isn't it the declaration of the same variable a ?